# Redirect from Offline IIS to Maintenance Site

Tags: asp.net, iis

To show people that the ASP.Net Application on the IIS Applicationpool is down for maintenance instead of an legitimate error, I need to redirect anyone calling a part (from bookmarks as well) of the application to an universal maintenance-page.

First I tried the route of using App_Offline in the root directory of the app. To no avail (IIS is down so the site cant be run). Then I tried the http-redirection which didn't work, for the same reason.

Comment: Is IIS completely down? Or just that one site? If it's just that one site, you could create another site with an error page (and a URL rewrite rule to make sure all paths hit the error message) and then swap the bindings so that users get directed to that site instead. If you need something more sophisticated, you'll probably need to have a load balancer with appropriate failover features sit between your clients and your web servers.

Comment: Edited the question - only the Applicationpool is offline

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to stop your app pool. The existence of app_offline.htm will shut down your application. There are more details about how it works [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/App_5F00_Offline.htm-and-working-around-the-_2200_IE-Friendly-Errors_2200_-feature).

However, that won't stop IIS from serving static HTML files. If you have static HTML files as part of your application, then you will have to redirect some other way. You could create a different site in IIS with your maintenance page. Then remove the binding for your live site and add it to your maintenance site while you do the work. Then move it back later.

*Update:* Here is some PowerShell I wrote that will wait until all connections are closed. It just looks at ports 443 and 80. You might need to modify it depending on your website:

```
$TCPProperties = [System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties]::GetIPGlobalProperties()

Do {
    $StillConnections = $FALSE
    $Connections = $TCPProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections()
    foreach ($Connection in $Connections) {
        if ($Connection.LocalEndPoint.Port -eq "443") {
            $StillConnections = $TRUE
            Break
        }
    }
    Start-Sleep -s 2
} While($StillConnections) 

Do {
    $StillConnections = $FALSE
    $Connections = $TCPProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections()
    foreach ($Connection in $Connections) {
        if ($Connection.LocalEndPoint.Port -eq "80") {
            $StillConnections = $TRUE
            Break
        }
    }
    Start-Sleep -s 2
} While($StillConnections)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly my coworker (who actually wants to have this feature) doesn't want to work with any of the two solutions.

Comment: Any other solution will most likely be far more complicated.

Comment: If you don't stop app pool, most of the time some files (eg, xyz.dll) are still under use by some processes, even if you place app_offline.html page. So if, for example, you want to show offline page for your automatic/complex deployments, this solution won't work perfrectly.

Comment: @Zeeshan Have you tried it? I just used it last week and was able to update an entire, complex site using an automatic deployment while using `app_offline.htm`. The documentation does say that "it will shut-down the app-domain for the application".

Comment: yes tried it. Usually it updates file with no issues. But some time it fails due to error reason mentioned in my last comment. My envronment: asp.net CORE, Windows, IIS. Deployment Tool: Bamboo (using script). I came across this post while looking for other solutions.

Comment: Regarding my last comment: it will actually not "fail". The bamboo finishes deployment with "Success" message. But it will skip some files sometimes. You can identify this from deployment logs. I found this issue out when my changes were not reflecting in new deployment, while babmoo deployment was successful. Then i kept observing logs and found error saying something like: "file is being used by another process" (or similar)

Comment: Ah, ASP.NET Core. Yes, ASP.NET Core behaves differently. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-3.1#in-process-hosting-model): "When using Web Deploy or manually placing an app_offline.htm file in the deployment, the app might not shut down immediately if there's an open connection. For example, a websocket connection may delay app shut down."

Comment: @Zeeshan I updated my answer with some code that I wrote a while ago to wait until all HTTP/HTTPS connections are closed. You could use that between adding the `app_offline.htm` file and updating your files to make sure the app is fully shut down.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Would it work without changing the bindings if we create a different site for maintenance mode with the same bindings and then just stop main site and start maintenance site? I read about this here [Offline / maintenance mode in IIS](https://www.vegaitsourcing.rs/media-center/blog/offline-maintenance-mode-in-iis) but I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: @ChristosLytras Sound like it would work. But there is always the chance that requests can come in between the time the main site shuts down and the maintenance site comes up.

Answer (score 0):

If you stop a Web site, means the Web site no longer listens for requests on all of its bindings. This prevents any subsequent requests from being received by your applications in the Web site; new connections to your Web site will fail as if it didn't exist.

So first start the application pool and create a temporary page which is used to redirect all the pages.

Below is URL rewrite rule which redirects all the pages to the under-construction page.

```
<rule name="RequestBlockingRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern=".*" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="temp.html" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="temp.html" />
            </rule>
```

[image]

if you want to redirect to another site you can set another site url in action URL value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But sadly I can't use your method because my coworker doesn't want to change the bindings.

Comment: This doesn't change the bindings.

Comment: @GabrielLuci said it does not change the bindings. you just need to add page and redirect all the request to that under construction page. this is just an example and i used my site binding.